# Halcon - how to handle different colored objects

Tags: brightness, halcon

I have objects with 3 different colors:
black, dark green, and bright blue.

When I take pictures of them, I do not yet know the real color of the object, thus my image can only be so bright that the bright blue object does not blow out to white. If I make the bright blue as bright as I can, then the dark green and the black are still very dark. Almost too much.

Is there anything that can be done beside brightening up the images afterward? 
the camera is a Genie Nano.

Answer (score 0):

If there is enough time, you could take multiple images with different exposure times. There is even a ready method in Halcon to merge light and dark images "create_high_dynamic_range_image.hdev".

If your application is time critical and camera manufacturer provides events for the language you're working in you can do the following:

- Put the camera in asynchronous acquisition (reduces time)
- Start acquisition with the lowest desired exposure time
- On each image event increase the exposure time for some step N times
- Since the camera is in asynchronous acquisition each exposure time comes after M frames (usually 5)
- First M images should be ignored, and after that you will have N-M images with gradually increased exposure time

Comment: thanks for your answer.. In my case I am taking pictures of fast moving parts in a precise position, so I do not have the possibility to take multiple shots. I was hoping in something like an auto exposure time based on a predefined analyzed region in the image....

Comment: How much time for acquisition do you have?